# Weird issue with is_pages() with array

Tags: pages

Does anybody know why this works:

```
if ( is_page( array( 'home', 'contact' ) ) ) {}
```

But this doesn’t:

```
$pages = array( 'home', 'contact' );
    if ( is_page( $pages ) ) {}
```

Even when adding `settype( $pages, 'array');`

Comment: That is weird.  What's the `var_dump()` look like for `$pages`?